# Right Join with regard to partitions in Athena Presto

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I'm fairly new to SQL and working with Athena AWS (Presto). 
I'm trying to take a very small dataset (a few GB) and join each of it's rows with information from a very large dataset (multiple TB).

I have a table called student_table, from which I take a particular student's activity (consisting of a few dozen rows). 
I want to give each student the event_id which is stored in a very big table. In both tables the partitions are year, month, day.

Here's my query thus far:

```
WITH student_hist AS (
SELECT 
    year,month,day,event_time,course,student_id,action
FROM students_table
WHERE 
    AND date_parse(concat(year, '-', month, '-', day),'%Y-%m-%d')
        BETWEEN DATE('2020-01-01') AND DATE('2020-06-01')
    AND student_id = '2594395350'
)

SELECT 
    student_hist.*
    ,events.id
FROM big_table events
RIGHT JOIN student_hist
    ON  CAST(student_hist.year AS INTEGER)  = big_table.year 
    AND CAST(student_hist.month AS INTEGER) = big_table.month
    AND CAST(student_hist.day AS INTEGER)   = big_table.day
    AND student_hist.event_time = big_table.event_time
```

When I query to get only student_hist my query uses about 20GB, but when I run the full query above to get the event_id, the query takes a huge amount of resources (many TB) and I have to cancel it (before I go broke). I think the problem is that the partitions are not being used in the RIGHT JOIN.

Do you have any idea how to get the partitions to work in the RIGHT JOIN? I've also tried to get the distinct dates from the student_hist, by replacing "FROM big_table events" above with :

```
FROM (SELECT * FROM big_table WHERE date_parse(...date partitions) IN (SELECT dates FROM distinct_dates)) events
```

But again the query uses too much resources. I think it's because it's running the subquery after IN over and over.

I want the 2nd part of the query to just take the partition according to each row in the student_hist. Student_hist has less that 100 rows overall so this query shouldn't take long or require huge amounts of data. Not sure why but it seems the partitions are not being used here.

Thank y'all for helping!

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find `main table LEFT JOIN optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data RIGHT JOIN main table`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that LEFT JOIN is more intuitive. But on Athena to save resources it's recommended to have the small table in the JOIN and the big table in the FROM. So I chose RIGHT JOIN here.

Comment: Interesting, and odd.

Comment: Can you maybe share the data scan / execution times of the different queries? :)